# Is a heap solution that replaces elements more efficient than one that pops then pushes?

Tags: python, heap

I am writing a solution to the following problem:
https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-stones-to-minimize-the-total/

My question is simply around comparing two solutions.

I am using a `max heap` to solve the problem, where I am taking the `max value` from the heap, doing some computation to it (where it becomes a smaller number), then pushing it back into the heap. Here is my code:

```
from math import floor
import heapq
def minStoneSum(piles, k: int) -> int:
    while k > 0:
        heapq._heapify_max(piles)
        max_pile = heapq._heappop_max(piles)
        remove_stones = floor(max_pile / 2)
        replacement = max_pile- remove_stones
        heapq.heappush(piles,replacement)
        k -= 1

    return sum(piles)

print(minStoneSum([5,4,9], 2))
```

While it passes most of the tests, it does produce a `Time Out error`.

I found another solution, which I think is extremely similar to mine:

```
def minStoneSum(self, piles: List[int], k: int) -> int:
        
        pq = [-x for x in piles]
        heapify(pq)
        for _ in range(k): 
            heapreplace(pq,pq[0]//2)
        return -sum(pq)
```

But this code passes all the tests! Is mine less efficient because I am popping the max, doing some computation the reinserting it? Whereas this code is simply replacing the max in each iteration?

Comment: There are several micro-optimisations between your code and the code you found. It's hard to guess which would be most significant without benchmarking every variation.

Comment: Thanks Kaya, that's what I thought, but how come the latter code passes all tests but mine doesn't? It would be good if anyone could point out where the major optimisations are- I pointed out what I thought it is, but not sure if I'm right

Comment: It doesn't seem to me that any of the optimisations are major. `heapreplace` should be more efficient than a `heappop` plus a `heappush`, but e.g. you're also doing float division instead of int division which means a lot of converting numbers unnecessarily, and there are other things like the extra subtraction, and accessing module members (using `.` notation) instead of as bare names. The only way to know which has most effect on the running time would be to do several comparisons with versions of the code which change one thing each; that sounds like work you would have to do yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`heapreplace` does not change the size of the heap, after replacing the value, the new value needs to sift *down* the heap in order to restore the heap property.

`_heappop_max` shortens the heap by moving the last value to the first slot, and sift *down* that value in the heap.

`heappush` will add the new value at the end and perform a sift *up*. However, is this action really heplfull, as `heappush` will assume a min-heap organisation... moving the new value most often at the wrong place. Which is why you need to heapify your heap repeatedly...

This is probably the most costly operation. Your code has a repeated call to `_heapify_max`, while the optimal solution only has to heapify once.

Comment: Thanks Trincot, very clear explanation. One clarification, so am I right in understanding that it is because I am popping() and pushing() items, and thus must call on heapify() to maintain the heap in each while loop. Whereas the more efficient solution is replacing() items in the heap (which reshuffles itself automatically), and thus is able to call on heapify only once?

Comment: Sorry, to make it clearer- if I didn't heapify() in each while loop, and instead just heappush() in each iteration would this make my solution just as efficient? Because heappush() maintains the heap invariant when pushing the new item into the heap!

Comment: You would need something like `_heapppush_max` instead of `heappush`, but apparently it doesn't exist, at least not under that name. The working solution negates all values, so that the standard methods of `heapq` can be used (i.e. as a min-heap), and not the undocumented `_` methods...

Comment: Good catch, I missed this somehow.

Comment: Okay thanks, but what if in my solution, I were to make all items negative as in the more efficient solution. Then simply use heappush(), would this work?

Comment: I mean would it work and be as efficient as in the efficient solution above?

Comment: It would come close, but `heappop`,  `heappush` and `heapreplace` all perform a sift operation, so it speaks for itself that using only one of those methods instead of two will save some time.